# using proposition for double induction

Tags: induction, recursion

I want to use double induction (induction on two variables, right?) and I'm unsure of how to use the proposition for recursive functions.
For a double induction I figured I needed two proofs, one for $x \rightarrow x+1$ and for $y \rightarrow y+1$.

Now let's say I want to proof $f(x,y) = x - y$ where $f$ is some recursive function declared prior to that. Part of this recursive function is $f(x,y) = f(x - 1, y - 1)$.

Proposition = $f(x,y) = x - y$

Step1: $x \rightarrow x+1$:
\begin{align*}
f(x + 1, y) &\stackrel{\text{Def. f}}{=} f(x, y - 1) \\&\stackrel{\text{Proposition}}{=} x - (y - 1) \\& etc.
\end{align*}

Step2: $y \rightarrow y+1$:
\begin{align*}
f(x, y + 1) &\stackrel{\text{Def. f}}{=} f(x - 1, y) \\&\stackrel{\text{Proposition}}{=} (x - 1) - y \\& etc.
\end{align*}

Is my use of the proposition right?

Furthermore if $f(x,y) = f(x - 2, y - 2)$.

Step1: $x \rightarrow x+1$:
\begin{align*}
f(x + 1, y) &\stackrel{\text{Def. f}}{=} f(x - 1, y - 2) \\&\stackrel{\text{Proposition}}{=} (x - 1) - (y - 2) \\& etc.
\end{align*}
would be wrong, right?

Comment: Is it part of the definition that $f(x,y) = f(x-1,y-1)$?  You write that as definition.  If it is then your method would work.  But other wise you may have to prove it.

Comment: @fleablood It's just something simple I thought of. Yes it is part of it.

Comment: What you are doing is good but it might be slick to do $P(n)::$ for all $x-y = n$ then $f(x,y)=n$.  Induction step:  If $x-y = n+1$ then $(x-1),y = n$ so $f(x-1,y)=n$ so .... somehow got $f(x,y) = n+1$.

Comment: @fleablood I added that to the question.

Comment: I don’t think this would be a meaningful induction on both variables. Your induction step moves in the same direction in both parts. In order to have induction on two variables, you’re two induction steps would need to move in different directions.

Comment: In theory this works.  In practice.... i'm not sure.  What exactly is the relation between these values.  What *is* you function and how is it defined.  Is there are reason you are reluctant to tell us what it is.

Comment: @fleablood I see this is more complicated than I thought. I'm gonna post the actual function in a new question.

Comment: Here's a case where it *ISN'T* true.  $f(a,b) = f(a-1,b-1)$. $f(a,a)= 0 = a-a$ and $f(0,a) = 2^a-1$.  Then we have $f(a,b) = 2^{b-a} - 1\ne b-a$.  Thing is we can have $f(x+1, y) = f(x,y-1)$ but we can not relate that in any way to $f(x,y)$ which is Robo300's point.  If however we knew something about how $f(x+1,y)$ relates to $f(x,y)$ (which we don't) then we certainly *could* do what you want..

Comment: I *slightly* disagree with robo300.  This has potential to be perfectly valid but you do need a way to relate $f(x+1,y)$ to $f(x,y)$.  However s/he is absolutely correct in pointing that $f(x,y) = f(x-1,y-1)$ which means $f(x+1,y) = f(x, y-1)$ and $f(x,y+1) = f(x-1,y)$ can only make jumps in "pairs".

Comment: @fleablood I posted the original function [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503312/proving-recursive-function-outputs-2x-x-choose-y). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You’re problem is, that you’re moving (-1,-1) , not (-1,0) and (0,-1).Suppose you use as your base case: f(0,0)=0; then you can only prove f(x,y)=x-y for pairs (x,y) where x-y=0. If you could prove it for all pairs of integers, then there would be no other function g such that g(x-1,y-1) =g(x,y) and g(0,0)= 0, however the function g(x,y)=5(x-y) is also a solution to these constraints. In order to prove f(x,y)=x-y for all (x,y), you would have to have a second relation, perhaps                  f(x,y) = f(x-1,y)+1, so you could move in more than one direction.